# rewriting/redirecting requests from one directory to another

Tags: .htaccess

I've just inherited a load of code that is set up to reside in a website root folder unfortunately named "tract".

Many of the files within that folder contain references to the path mywebsite.com/tract.

I'd like to rename the folder to "login" - but I don't want to go through miles of code and change every reference to "tract" to "login" - if I can help it.

I'd like to know if there's a way, using .htaccess, for me to be able to make links to mywebsite.com/login (e.g., mywebsite.com/login/register.php), and for that address to appear in the browser, but to be 'actually' pointing to mywebsite.com/tract (e.g., mywebsite.com/tract/register.php).

Is this possible?

I'm on a shared server and I only have access to .htaccess, not to other configuration files.

Comment: I did Google it, and found stackoverflow, so I joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^login(/.*|)$ tract$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: anubhava - many thanks - this worked:

`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews  
# Turn mod_rewrite on  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^login(/.*|)$ tract$1 [L,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL rewriting and something like that.
Apache rewrite module must be activated (mod_rewrite)

`RewriteRule       ^mywebsite.com/tract(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$    mywebsite.com/login`